# Is the Civil 3D API available?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to access Civil 3D Object properties and methods. Are these available in Forge?

Searched online docs, but not specified.

No sample code, but looking for surface volume functions.

.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Forge with Civil 3D drawings, they are translated just fine with Model Derivative and show with properties on Viewer, see [this example](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/civil-3d-data-forge-viewer).